# Pickuping the Common 1d sequence in 1d array's?

Tags: c++

How to pick the best uniformed 1d array from the 2d arrays ?

I have two 2d array of : 11 x 10 
Example :

```
  4 8 12 12 12 14 16 18 4 1 0 
  5 7 11 12 13 11 15 18 3 2 1
  8 3 12 14 18 19 20 21 8 5 4 ,
  8 2 11 12 17 17 19 20 7 4 3 ,
  4 7 11 11 11 15 17 19 5 1 1 ,
  3 8 11 13 11 15 14 17 4 1 0 ,
  4 7 12 13 13 14 16 19 3 1 1 ,
  5 9 11 12 13 15 17 19 5 0 1 ,
  9 7 25 22 24 18 23 17 3 3 3 ,
  4 8 13 13 13 15 17 17 5 2 0 ,
```

here we have 2d arrays of size 11x10 - Need to analysis and have to find out the common 1d array which has common like.

find the best closing number and its difference- and keep doing for all the corresponding columns in an array .

below  answer should be like - finding the corresponding very column and comparing with the next row column - if it has some difference below ( 5 ) take the both column of two rows are same and process for next column of the same row..process untill finding the 1 row where it has at least nearby matches of  5

```
4 8 11 12 13 13 15 18 4 1 0
```

Comment: I can't understand what it is you're trying to achieve. Please try to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Need to compare all corresponding columns in all rows and have to find out the uniform or common or near by 1d array in all rows

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what that means.

Comment: @zmbq Its like kind of averaging ? but not exactly the same - 1. instead of that finding out the difference  between corresponding columns in all rows 2. Finding the minimum differences between all columns 3. which column and rows has very minimum and most number of occurrences or near by value - that is the answer

Comment: so you need to look through each column and which ever number appears the most, this is the number that will be outputted? That sort of thing?

Comment: does this sound like an algorithm problem?

Comment: @Flyphe yes not exactly have to look for most repeated number, we can count it even if it very closer to that ( for Ex : 5 or 10 - difference is allowed ) - i tried it but stuck up in the start, don know where to start ???

Comment: @zinking yes its algorithm . Finding out the most common or near by corresponding numbers in rows

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do something like this

```
int[] count(int[][] array)
int result[11];

for(int x = o; x<= 11;x++)
{
int temp[10];
 for(int y = o; y<= 10;y++)
{
 temp[y] = array[y][x];
}
result[x] = getHighest(temp);
}
return result;
}

int getHighest(int[] array)
{
 int size = array.length;
 int[size][1] temp; 

 for(int x; x<= size;x++)
{
 int z = array[x];
 temp[z][0]++;

}
int highest = -1;
for(int z; z<= size;z++)
{
 int z = array[x];
 int h = temp[z][0];
 if(h > highest)
 {
  highest = h;
 }
}
return highest;
}
```

Something like this, but my C++ has gotten a bit of rusty so sorry if there are any mistakes.